# Physics like asteroides

Tags: java

I try to make a ship that has the physic properties like asteroides.
I have this for now(All in Java):

**Ship.class**

```
public class Ship
{
    public static final float sMaxHealth            = 0.1F;
    public static final float sMaxMoveVelocity      = 5.0F;
    public static final float sMaxAngleVelocity     = 20.0F;
    public static final float sRadius               = 1.0F;
    public static final float sMoveDeceleration     = 10.0F;
    public static final float sMoveAcceleration     = 2.0F;
    public static final float sAngleDeceleration    = 15.0F;
    public static final float sAngleAcceleration    = 20.0F;


    private float mHealth;
    private float mXVelocity;
    private float mYVelocity;
    private float mAngleVelocity;

    private float mX;
    private float mY;
    private float mAngle;
}
```

(I let the getter and setter away for now)

**Controller code**

```
        // Player input
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP))
        {
            mPlayer.setXVelocity(mPlayer.getXVelocity() + (float) Math.cos(mPlayer.getAngle()) * Ship.sMoveAcceleration);
            mPlayer.setYVelocity(mPlayer.getYVelocity() + (float) Math.sin(mPlayer.getAngle()) * Ship.sMoveAcceleration);
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT))
        {
            mPlayer.setAngleVelocity(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() + Ship.sAngleAcceleration * pDeltaTime);
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
        {
            mPlayer.setAngleVelocity(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() - Ship.sAngleAcceleration * pDeltaTime);
        }

        // X velocity
        if(mPlayer.getXVelocity() < 0)
        {
            if(-mPlayer.getXVelocity() > Ship.sMaxMoveVelocity)
            {
                mPlayer.setXVelocity(-Ship.sMaxMoveVelocity);
            }
            mPlayer.setXVelocity(mPlayer.getXVelocity() + Ship.sMoveDeceleration * pDeltaTime);
            if(mPlayer.getXVelocity() > 0)
            {
                mPlayer.setXVelocity(0);
            }
        }
        else
        if(mPlayer.getXVelocity() > 0)
        {
            if(mPlayer.getXVelocity() > Ship.sMaxMoveVelocity)
            {
                mPlayer.setXVelocity(Ship.sMaxMoveVelocity);
            }
            mPlayer.setXVelocity(mPlayer.getXVelocity() - Ship.sMoveDeceleration * pDeltaTime);
            if(mPlayer.getXVelocity() < 0)
            {
                mPlayer.setXVelocity(0);
            }
        }

        // Y velocity
        if(mPlayer.getYVelocity() < 0)
        {
            if(-mPlayer.getYVelocity() > Ship.sMaxMoveVelocity)
            {
                mPlayer.setYVelocity(-Ship.sMaxMoveVelocity);
            }
            mPlayer.setYVelocity(mPlayer.getYVelocity() + Ship.sMoveDeceleration * pDeltaTime);
            if(mPlayer.getYVelocity() > 0)
            {
                mPlayer.setYVelocity(0);
            }
        }
        else
        if(mPlayer.getYVelocity() > 0)
        {
            if(mPlayer.getYVelocity() > Ship.sMaxMoveVelocity)
            {
                mPlayer.setYVelocity(Ship.sMaxMoveVelocity);
            }
            mPlayer.setYVelocity(mPlayer.getYVelocity() - Ship.sMoveDeceleration * pDeltaTime);
            if(mPlayer.getYVelocity() < 0)
            {
                mPlayer.setYVelocity(0);
            }
        }

        // Angle velocity
        if(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() < 0)
        {
            if(-mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() > Ship.sMaxAngleVelocity)
            {
                mPlayer.setAngleVelocity(-Ship.sMaxAngleVelocity);
            }
            mPlayer.setAngleVelocity(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() + Ship.sAngleDeceleration * pDeltaTime);
            if(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() > 0)
            {
                mPlayer.setAngleVelocity(0);
            }
        }
        else
        if(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() > 0)
        {
            if(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() > Ship.sMaxAngleVelocity)
            {
                mPlayer.setAngleVelocity(Ship.sMaxAngleVelocity);
            }
            mPlayer.setAngleVelocity(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() - Ship.sAngleDeceleration * pDeltaTime);
            if(mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() < 0)
            {
                mPlayer.setAngleVelocity(0);
            }
        }

        mPlayer.setX(mPlayer.getX() + mPlayer.getXVelocity() * pDeltaTime);
        mPlayer.setY(mPlayer.getY() + mPlayer.getYVelocity() * pDeltaTime);
        mPlayer.setAngle(mPlayer.getAngle() + mPlayer.getAngleVelocity() * pDeltaTime);
```

Why the ship does not behave like in asteroides ?
What do I wrong?

Comment: mmh look to my code and tell me what is wrong...  not so sure this is the right place for such.

Comment: How would an asteroid behave? You're not describing what you expect and what actually happens. Be more precise please

Comment: How *does* your ship behave and in what way does this behavior differ from how you *want* it to behave? (No, we will not test your code)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean [this game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_%28game%29).

I suggest that you take a look at the [Wikipedia references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_%28game%29#References) for the game. One of them tells you that both drag and inertia are involved - I don't see any drag in your code for a start.